# URL rewriting removing question mark and replace it with slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite a URL from `http://example.com/product.php?categoryid=1` to `http://example.com/product/categoryid/1`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /product.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (GET|HEAD)\ /product\.php\?([^=]+)=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /product/%2/%3?%4 [L,R=301]
```

Those rules need to be in the htaccess file in your document root. You may also need to create a base for all of you relative URL links, adding this to the header of your page should fix it:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...@Jon Lin but when m inserting your code in htaccess file its not working, its output as same as previous and insert <base href="/" /> in head section, my style sheet also not working, i am working on localhost. Do you have another code for it?